# Copying to clipboard on Kotlin Multiplatform

Tags: android, kotlin, android-context, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform

I couldn't find anyone doing this so far so I'll try and properly state the issues I am facing.

I have a `compose-ui` module in the `shared module` of my KMP app. The `compose-ui` has a `commonMain` directory where all of the compose UI resides (screens that are shared between the desktop and the android app). Now the issue is, to copy the text to the clipboard (on Android) you need Context, which cannot be accessed in the commonMain, okay, no issues, I'll have to expect/ actual function `@Composable copyToClipboard(text: string)`, but using the `IconButton` and its `OnClick : () -> Unit` which results in an error that `@Composable can only be called from composable context`. I am not sure how to go about this, I somehow need context to access the clipboard manager but I cannot access it nor pass it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work, it your androidMain:

```
@Composable
fun copyClipboardLambda(): () -> Unit {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    return {
        context.yourCopyFunc()
    }
}
```

In your View:

```
@Composable
fun View() {
    val copyClipboard = copyClipboardLambda()
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.clickable {
            copyClipboard()
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work in a multiplatform context i.e desktop as context doesn't exist in a desktop client

Comment: @Breimer `copyClipboardLambda` should be `expect` function, provided implementation is for android, and desktop implementation will be different, as it doesn't have context.